# How to fix Error 18456, Severity 14, State 38 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, ssms, error-log

I have combed the internet trying to fix the next error:

```
    Login failed for user 'NN\SW-DATA$'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'SSISDB'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
```

The articles on this site I have read too, but it didn't help. I have deleted SSIDB and creating and deleting again, with the help of using XEvent and SQL Profiler I trying to find out which the app is connecting , I checked all job either there is connection to SSISDB, I was stopping different sql serveces to stop this errors, nothing works.
This errors occures every minute and SQl logs are becoming huge so fast!

I will be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Confused: you have an app that is trying to connect but failing, or you have the logs and are unsure which app it is?

Comment: Seems like you have an `NN\SW-DATA$` Windows login, but there's no database user mapping for it in the `SSISDB` database so it doesn't have access.

Comment: Charlieface, I have the logs and unsure where does it come from

Comment: AlwaysLearning, I don't understand, why NN\SW-Data$ stil try to access even database is deleted? And if it is the cause of problem how can I fix it?